# How to check if some process is running in task manager with python

Tags: python, process

I have one function in python which should start running when some process (eg. proc.exe) showed up in tasks manager.
How can I monitor processes running in tasks manager with python?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 10):

here is something, I've adapted from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/python/pyindex.mspx?mfr=true)

```
import win32com.client
strComputer = "."
objWMIService = win32com.client.Dispatch("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
objSWbemServices = objWMIService.ConnectServer(strComputer,"root\cimv2")
colItems = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")
for objItem in colItems:
   print "Name: ", objItem.Name
   print "File location: ", objItem.ExecutablePath
```

There is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/scripts/python/pyindex.mspx?mfr=true) a lot of nice examples for python and windows

Update: objItem.ExecutablePath gives the file location of the exe

Answer (score 0):

Try the WMI module:
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/cookbook.html